# tlp settings not working

Tags: joystick, tlp

Yesterday I tried to play a game with my joystick and it was being disabled and enabled all the time. To fix that, I've downloaded `tlp` and added my device ID to the blacklist. Worked like a charm. Today I turned on my computer again and tried to play the game again, with no luck, the disabling/enabling problem was back, it seems the tlp settings aren't working.

`sudo tlp-stat` returns the following:

```
+++ USB
autosuspend        = enabled
device whitelist   = (not configured)
device blacklist   = 0079:0006
wwan blacklist     = enabled

Bus 002 Device 038 ID 0079:0006 control = on,   autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- DragonRise Inc. PC TWIN SHOCK Gamepad (usbhid)
```

From what I understand it should be working. Does anyone have any idea about what is happening? I'm running an Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Your output clearly shows that the blacklist setting works. "control = on" means that autosuspend is disabled. I guess it will even stay that way if you disable TLP or uninstall it, because its the kernel default for most drivers.

Probably your problem is not related to power saving but to some kernel driver malfunction. I suggest you check dmesg outputs.

ps. blacklisting is redundant in your case, because TLP excludes usbhid anyway.